# Generate events in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I will insert records into a collection in MongoDB. The record will have a field of type 'Timestamp'. This field will have values that are in future time. 
(Ex: i insert the record today and the field can have a value of tomorrow.)

Question is can MongoDb generate an event when, currentTime == value of the field

If it can generate event, how can my application register/listen to that event

I know that when you insert/update/delete records, application can listen to opLog to get notified about these events. What i need is more specific

Comment: No, this is outside of Mongo's scope.

Answer (score 0):

> can MongoDb generate an event when, currentTime == value of the field ?

No.

As of now<sup>1</sup> there is no such thing in MongoDB. But there is the *planned but not scheduled* JIRA [SERVER-124](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124) request to add trigger support to MongoDB. You might vote for that -- or take place to the discussion -- or even invest yourself in the development if you need that feature !

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> MongoDB 3.0.3 was the latest stable version when I wrote this</sub>